# Frankfurt best Star Alliance lounge at Terminal 1 (international) departure

Tags: turkish-airlines, frankfurt, lounges, star-alliance

Next week I fly out of Frankfurt on Turkish airlines (economy) and there are several lounges available on Star Alliance Gold.

Any recommendations on which might be the best lounge to use? I am confused with the multiple options available.

This is in the international departures area of Terminal 1 (not sure if Turkish gates are in a particular concourse / wing of Terminal 1).

Answer (score 6):

Terminal 1 at Frankfurt is broken into multiple different "concourses" - A, B, C and Z.  Each of these concourse contains one or more Lufthansa lounges.  In general, the best lounge to use is dictated by the location of the gate your flight is departing from. It is possible to access the other lounges in other concourses, although in many cases this will require passing through immigration and/or security - and generally there isn't any point as most of the lounges offer very similar services.

As Star Alliance Gold you have access to both the the Lufthansa Business Lounges and the Lufthansa Senator Lounges - the latter being slightly better, but only slightly.  In most cases the two lounges are paired together (with a single entrance), although there are a few exceptions.

Specifically for Turkish flights, these generally leave from the B concourse. The nearest lounge would be the "Lufthansa B East" lounges which are above gates B44-48, and which contains both a Business and Senator lounge.  Additionally there is also a Business lounge on the west end of the terminal, but this is not as good as the East one.

Answer (score 2):

Frankfurt also has a landside lounge on terminal 1. It might be an option depending how early you arrive at the airport and wether you have check in luggage.
I use to travel a few hours by Deutsche Bahn train to Frankfurt. When my train is not delayed I arrive there before the luggage drop off opens and I go to this lounge. It was slightly worse than the Air France lounge at terminal 2, but a really good option for waiting before luggage drop off opens.
PS: apparently this lounge is not available for Star Alliance gold. It is available for loungeKey, dragonPass and probably a few others.

Comment: There are a few lounges land-side, however none of them are free to access as Star Alliance Gold.